# PHP ftp_put function file limitation?

Tags: php, limit

i want to sending the current 30k files to the remote server that has the ftp_put function. But the page timed out because it was trying to send them all. I want to send the specified number of files each time the page is refreshed. For example, 50 files for each refresh. Can someone help me do this? I searched the solution a lot, but I couldn't find any information. I didn't know exactly how to search on the internet because my English isn't very good, thank you.

```
<?php
$file = 'critical_logs/'.$entry;
$send_to = 'httpdocs/abc/'.$entry;

$conn = ftp_connect('ftp.example.com');
if (!$conn) die('ftp.example.com connect error'); 
$login_result = ftp_login($conn, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

if (ftp_put($conn, $file, $send_to, FTP_ASCII)) {
 echo "success\n";
} else {
 echo "error\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: I think this is just SOME of the code - presumably this is in a loop? Where/how are the files selected?

Comment: Why not use cron for that?

Comment: That's the first part of my code.

if ($handle = opendir('logs')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            $hop[] = $entry;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
srand((float) microtime() * 1000000);
shuffle($hop);
foreach ($hop as $entry)

Comment: @Justinas I can't use cron. What do I need to add to the code for the limit operation?

Comment: `set_time_limit(0);` and just leave it running

Comment: @Dale Doesn't it still leaves browser and server timeouts?

Comment: put that `set_time_limit(0);` at the top of the script, run it in the browser and leave it going, presuming you have your code in a loop it should keep going until it finishes

Comment: @Justinas You got [ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial idea I had was to obtain a list of files in the `critical_logs` directory and record them to file. The logfile must be in a different directory to prevent it being sent to the FTP server. Once that list of files exists process the file in chunks of, in your case, 50 at a time. Once the 50 files have been processed the logfile is updated to remove those entries - thus on the next page load the process can begin again. An example, tested but without any FTP testing

```
    set_time_limit(0);
    error_reporting( E_ALL );


    $chunksize=20;          # set to 50
    $use_ftp_cmds=false;    # set as true to actually attempt FTP commands

    $ftp_host='ftp.example.com';
    $ftp_send_to='httpdocs/abs/';


    /* find all files in directory */
    $dir = __DIR__ . '/critical_logs/';
    $files = glob( $dir . '*.*' );

    /* create, if it does not exist, a log to record the files - in parent directory */
    chdir('..\\');
    $log = getcwd() . '/files.txt';

    /* add record for each file */
    if( !file_exists( $log ) ){
        foreach( $files as $file ){
            file_put_contents( $log, $file . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
        }
    }
    /* process the file in chunks */
    if( file_exists( $log ) ){
        clearstatcache();

        $lines = file( $log, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );
        if( count( $lines ) > 0 ){

            $chunks = array_chunk( $lines, $chunksize );

            /* connect to FTP server */
            if( $use_ftp_cmds ){

                $conn = ftp_connect( $ftp_host );
                if( !$conn ) die( sprintf( '%s connect error', $ftp_host ) );

                $login_result = ftp_login( $conn, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass );
                if( !$login_result ) die( 'Failed to login to FTP server' );
            }





            /* Process the first chunk */
            $chunk = array_shift( $chunks );

            foreach( $chunk as $file ){
                /* ftp cmds */
                $result = $use_ftp_cmds ? ftp_put( $conn, $file, sprintf( '%s/%s', $ftp_send_to, $file ) , FTP_ASCII ) : true;
                if( $result ){
                    /* remove the line from the source file and save updated version */
                    array_splice( $lines, array_search( $file, $lines ), 1 );
                }
            }


            file_put_contents( $log, '' );

            foreach( $lines as $line ){
                file_put_contents( $log, $line . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
            }

        } else {
            printf('The file %s is empty',$log);
        }
    }
```

Comment: :-) great news - glad it helped!